# Purge job optimization

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

I have a database with 3 tables that I am keeping a retention time of 15 days.  This is a logging database that is very active and about 500 GB in size and eats about 30GB a day unless purged.  I can't seem to get caught up on one of the tables and I am falling behind.  This table has 220 million rows and it needs to purge around 10-12 million rows nightly.  I am currently at 30 million rows needed to purge.  I can only run this purge at night due to the volume of incoming inserts competing for table locks.  I have confirmed that everything is indexed correctly and have run Brent Ozars sp_Blitz_Index just to confirm that.  Is there any way to optimize what I am doing below?  I am running the same purge steps for each table.

1. Drop and Create 3 purge tables: Purge_Log, Purge_SLogHeader and Purge_SLogMessage.

2.Insert rows into the purge tables (Takes 5 minutes each table):

```
Insert Into Purge_Log
Select ID from ServiceLog 
where startTime <  dateadd (day, -15, getdate()  )
```

--****************************************************

```
Insert into Purge_SLogMessage
select serviceLogId from ServiceLogMessage 
where serviceLogId in ( select id from 
                       ServiceLog 
                       where startTime <  dateadd (day, -15, getdate() ))
```

--****************************************************

```
Insert into Purge_SLogHeader
Select serviceLogId from ServiceLogHeader
where serviceLogId in ( select id from 
                       ServiceLog 
                       where startTime <  dateadd (day, -15, getdate()  ))
```

After that is inserted, then I run the following with differences for each table:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1000

delete_more:
delete from ServiceLog
where Id in ( select Id from Purge_Log)

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 GOTO delete_more
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Basically does anyone see a way that I can make this procedure run faster or have a different way to go about it.  I've made the queries as simple as possible and with only one subquery.  I've used a join and the execution query plan says the time is the same to complete it that way.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: To start with you should stop using ROWCOUNT like this. Using this for deletes like that is deprecated. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx You should instead use a loop to do batch deletes. And GOTO should be removed from your thoughts as a viable coding practice. I don't quite get the point of having a separate table for Purge_Log. Why not just delete the rows at the beginning instead of copying them all to another table?

Comment: Thank you for looking at this.   I will look into the loops for a delete option and re-evaluate GOTO.  I didn't delete the rows at the beginning because include the where clause in the delete took much more time to search through  220 million rows for a date.  I was prefetching those to the new tables and then running the delete against them to increase delete speed.

Comment: You can also consider partioning,since you are using enterprise version..Check out this links..https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2780/archiving-sql-server-data-using-partitioning

Comment: This one as well:http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108607/will-table-partitioning-and-compression-help-heavily-used-oltp-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this technique for all the tables, collect IDs first in temporary table to avoid scanning original table again and again in huge data. I hope it will work perfectly for you all the tables:

```
DECLARE @del_query VARCHAR(MAX)
```

/*
Taking IDs from ServiceLog table instead of Purge_Log because Purge_Log may have more data than expected because of frequent purging
 */

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_log_ids') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp_log_ids
SELECT ID INTO #tmp_log_ids FROM ServiceLog WHERE startTime < DATEADD(DAY, -15, GETDATE())

SET @del_query ='
DELETE TOP(100000) sl
FROM ServiceLog sl 
INNER JOIN #tmp_log_ids t ON t.id = s1.id'
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    EXEC(@del_query + ' option(maxdop 5) ')
    IF @@rowcount < 100000 BREAK;
END 

SET @del_query ='
DELETE TOP(100000) sl
FROM ServiceLogMessage sl 
INNER JOIN #tmp_log_ids t ON t.id = s1.serviceLogId'
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    EXEC(@del_query + ' option(maxdop 5) ')
    IF @@rowcount < 100000 BREAK;
END

SET @del_query ='
DELETE TOP(100000) sl
FROM ServiceLogHeader sl 
INNER JOIN #tmp_log_ids t ON t.id = s1.serviceLogId'
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    EXEC(@del_query + ' option(maxdop 5) ')
    IF @@rowcount < 100000 BREAK;
END
```

Comment: Adding the where dateadd clause to the delete adds significant time to the delete process due to the number of records it has to read through.

Comment: Yes, but still this query is faster than the using the IN condition because I am using the same query for one table with huge data after experiencing more techniques, it proves faster than others.

Comment: That will work for the ServiceLog table, but the problem is the other two tables do not contain the date field and I have to pull that from ServiceLog where ServiceLog.ID = OtherTables.serviceLogId.